# If statement with two conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large pandas sheet where I want to manipulate the wind direction based on the components of the wind speed. Currently I have this:

```
u=new2_df["U component of wind at 850 Mb over the landfall grid point"].values
v=new2_df["v component of wind at 850 Mb over the landfall grid point"].values
wind_speed=np.sqrt(u**2+v**2)
wind_dir_calc=np.arctan(v/u)
wind_dir=np.degrees(wind_dir_calc)
if np.all(u>0) & np.all(v>0):
  wind_dir=360-wind_dir-180
#if np.all(u>0) and np.all(v<0):
  #wind_dir=wind_dir+180
#if np.all(u<0) and np.all(v<0):
  #wind_dir=180-wind_dir+180
#if np.all(u<0) and np.all(v>0):
  #wind_dir=wind_dir
```

However, doing this if statement doesn't change the value of my array wind_dir. I want to first calculate the wind direction using u and v, then I want to modify the wind direction based on whether u and v were positive/negative during the wind direction calculation.

Comment: That doesn't change the any of the values in my original array.

Comment: Have you tried to evaluate whether your `if` is actually True?

Comment: No, how would I go about this?

Comment: Just check the return from `np.all(u>0)` and see if it is `True`... the same of `v>0` . Maybe you think you get every value greater than zero but don't

Comment: Oh. I think I shouldn't be using np.all. I thought using np.all() would select the entire array, but this doesn't seem to be happening. When I just do if u>0 and v>0:, I get the error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.

Comment: Are you trying to change individual element values or the whole array?

Comment: Look, `u` and `v` are arrays. What is the logic you are trying to implement ? Your code right now works as the following: *if **all** values from u **and all** values from v are greater than zero, then change the `wind_dir` array*. Is this what you want?

Comment: I am trying to only change certain elements of the wind_dir array. So from above, I calculate the wind direction using the arctan of u and v. I want to essentially make my code so that it will change individual elements based on the logic tests I have provided.

Comment: If you want to change *some* values based on this condition, then go with jpp's answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to essentially make my code so that it will change individual
>   elements based on the logic tests I have provided.

If I understand correctly, you can use a Boolean array with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
wind_dir[np.where((u > 0) & (v > 0))] = 180 - wind_dir
```

The logic will replace, for all indices where `u > 0` and `v > 0`, the corresponding values in `wind_dir` with `180 - wind_dir`.

Here's a demonstration:

```
A = np.array([0, -5, 2, 3, -2])
B = np.array([0, 2, -2, 6, 6])
C = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

C.flat[np.where((A > 0) & (B > 0))] = 180-C

print(C)
array([  1,   2,   3, 179,   5])
```

Using [`np.ndarray.flat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html) ensures the index array shape is aligned with the value array shape via an iterator.

Comment: This is what I want. But doing that runs me into the error that the shape of my wind_dir is different than the shape of u>0 and v>0, since not all of the entries in the array have u>0 and v>0. Does this make sense?

shape mismatch: value array of shape (26406,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (20049,)

Comment: @EliTurasky, Nope, it works fine for me. I've updated with an example.

Comment: I understand that it should work and your example makes sense. But I am getting that exact error, even when I copied and pasted your solution. Not sure what's happening.

Comment: Hmm, I get a warning, which disappears when I use `C.flat` (as per update). If you are copy-pasting *exactly* what I have above and it's still not working, can you say what NumPy version you're using?

Comment: The inclusion of .flat seems to have worked. Would you mind quickly explaining how .flat avoided the error? Thank you so much.

Comment: @EliTurasky, Sure, it aligns the right-hand side (which is a complete array) with the left-hand side (which is filtered) by using an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `jpp's` `flat` is a mask

```
mask = np.where((A > 0) & (B > 0))
C[mask] = 180 - C[mask]
```

With his small example the timing is the same.

`ufunc` like `np.add` also take a `where` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda on the boundary between comment and answer, because it's addressing issues with the question, rather than answering the question exactly as asked, but:

1. Doing `if np.all(u>0) & np.all(v>0)`, as the word "all" suggests, conditions on *all* the values being negative. So if there are any positive values, none of the data points are changed. If you want each data point to be based solely on the values for that measurement, you need to be broadcasting your condition over the arrays, rather than using the aggregation `all`.

2 . `wind_dir=360-wind_dir-180` is a rather convoluted way of writing `wind_dir=180-wind_dir`, and I don't understand why you want to do this. If you want to get angles in the third quadrant, you should do `wind_dir=180+wind_dir`. You current code puts the angle in the second quadrant. If you had `wind_dir=360-(180-wind_dir)`, that would make more sense, although it still be very convoluted.

3. This doesn't distinguish between the second and fourth quadrants.
4. numpy has a function [arctan2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) that takes two arguments and gives a signed angle based on the point given by those arguments (note that the y-coordinate is the first argument).